# Redux-Persist doesn't hydrate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I encountered a problem where based on redux-logger data persist and rehydrate method is called on each refresh. However, any of my data is retrieved :/

Tried on inserting whilelist property to check whether at least any of the reducer works, but no luck on that.

Have a code, which for me looks the same (in terms of redux-persist implementation) and works. Unfortunately, not for this project.
Should mention, that the previous project have React version of V17 and redux of v4. This project have React V18, redux - V4

Here is the code snippets:

root-reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import User from "../reducers/user/user.reducer";
import UIReducer from "../reducers/ui/ui.reducer";
import ReservationReducer from "../reducers/reservation/reservation.reducer";
import RestaurantsReducer from "../reducers/restaurants/restaurants.reducer";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: User,
  ui: UIReducer,
  reservation: ReservationReducer,
  restaurants: RestaurantsReducer,
});

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

store.js

```
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";

import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";
import rootSaga from "./root-sagas";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, logger];

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

And finally, index.js

```
import { persistor, store } from "./redux/store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```